# What is "Carrier Location Service"?

Tags: location-services

What is Carrier Location Service in Android?

If I try to allow it, there are 3 options:

1. Allow all the time
2. Allow only when using the app
3. Deny

What are the effects?

Comment: What you describe is the request if an app is allowed to access your location. Are you sure this request is for the Carrier Services app?

Comment: I couldn't really find references to "Carrier Location Service", but I found "Carrier Location Access" instead on OnePlus ([1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/carrier-location-access-permission-request-after-update.4102631/), [2](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/carrier-location-access.1154676/)) and MotoG ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/j3zom9/carrier_location_access/))

Answer (score 0):

It is `com.coloros.locationproxy`.

It is actually a system app found in Color OS,Realme UI, Funtouch OS, Oxygen OS (Color OS based versions), etc (basically OSs of brands under BBK Electronics)